# Is it correct to declare a dynamic array of atomic using double pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, atomic, pointer-to-pointer

I need to create an array of atomic integers i.e. n integers each of which are atomic. I found that `std::vector<std::atomic<int>>` will not work but then I tried the following approach and it compiles successfully with clang.

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
std::atomic<int> **a;
a = new std::atomic<int>* [n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    a[i] = new std::atomic<int>();
}
```

I'm not sure if doing this is correct, is it? Also, is there any method to verify if all the `a[i][0]` will be atomic here(except for checking it with multiple threads)?

Comment: `I found that std::vector<std::atomic<int>> will not work`. What did you try? `std::vector<std::atomic<int>> a(n);` very much works.

Comment: What do you mean by "checking if all `a[i][0]` are atomic"? Their type is `std::atomic<int>`, what else do you need to know?

Comment: I was trying to call `resize()` on the `std::vector<std::atomic<int>>` and that was causing the problem. But yes, it works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct (except for resource leaks, I assume destroying the arrays has been omitted for brevity), but complicated. First of all, why do you use a "double pointer" or pointers to pointers? Why not this:

```
std::atomic<int> * a1 = new std::atomic<int>[ n ];
```

If this works for you, then

```
std::vector<std::atomic<int>> a2( n );
```

should work too, there are a few differences, but the most important one probably is that if you pass `a1` by value, the contents are not copied, but if you pass in `a2` by value, they are.

This might be a problem for you, because `std::atomic` is not copyable. So you should always pass `a2` by reference, except if you need to transfer ownership; in that case use `std::move` and rvalue references. You can't pass `a2` by value.